# Center maps in iOS Programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, maps

How do we follow the user in maps. I want to have the blue dot (user location) be in the center of the map, But I also what to allow the user to zoom in and zoom out and then after a couple seconds zoom in back in the user location.

**My Educated Guess for the Solution:** We detect if the user is zooming in or out, after three seconds of no zooming in or out detection, we starting follow the user :). Your HELP would be awesome :)

This code zoom in the user location but doesn't delay for zoom in and out:

```
     - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
              fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

  MKCoordinateRegion userLocation = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate, 1500.0, 1500.0); [mapView setRegion:userLocation animated:YES];


    }
```

Comment: I thank everyone who up-voted my question and tried to answer it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a little example to show how you can delegate this job to the Map SDK. 
Of course you could listen to the Location change but MKUserTrackingModeFollow automatically does this for you, so just a single line of code

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

    //Always center the dot and zoom in to an apropriate zoom level when position changes
    [mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow];

    //don't let the user drag around the the map -> just zooming enabled
    [mapView setScrollEnabled:NO];

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}
```

Then the app looks like this:
[image: App with TrackingMode]
[image: App zoomed out in TrackingMode]

For more information just read the Apple Documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

Comment: I have Labels on the top of the map and your code hides   //[self.view addSubview:mapView];  :(

Comment: you don't need to put another mapview on the view just call //Always center the dot and zoom in to an apropriate zoom level when position changes
    [mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow];

    //don't let the user drag around the the map -> just zooming enabled
    [mapView setScrollEnabled:NO]; on your mapView containing the Labels. If this is not clear please post your code

Answer (score 13):

A quick look in the docs reveals the magic.
Set the `userTrackingMode` of your map to `MKUserTrackingModeFollow`.
See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html).

---

### Update:

Since you've updated your question, here's the new answer.
To recenter the map to the user location i would recommend to write a simple helper Method:

```
- (void)recenterUserLocation:(BOOL)animated{
    MKCoordinateSpan zoomedSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1000, 1000);

    MKCoordinateRegion userRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate, zoomedSpan);

    [self.mapView setRegion:userRegion animated:animated];
}
```

And now you should call it after a short delay if user has stopped moving the map. You can do this in the `regionDidChange` delegate method of the mapView.

But you can get problems if you don't lock the reset-method if the user changes the region multiple times before it really resets the map. So it would be wise to make a flag if it is possible to recenter the map. Like a property `BOOL canRecenter`.

Init it with `YES` and update the `recenterUserLocation` method to:

```
- (void)recenterUserLocation:(BOOL)animated{
    MKCoordinateSpan zoomedSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1000, 1000);

    MKCoordinateRegion userRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate, zoomedSpan);

    [self.mapView setRegion:userRegion animated:animated];

    self.canRecenter = YES;
}
```

Now you can call it safely after the user has moved the map in any way with a small delay:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mMapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
    if (self.canRecenter){
        self.canRecenter = NO;
        [self performSelector:@selector(recenterUserLocation:) withObject:@(animated) afterDelay:3];
    }
}
```

Comment: Code doesn't zoom in the user Location :(

Comment: ... You really should start to find things like this yourself. Best way is to **read** the docs. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Hi, @yinkou! I came here searching for an answer to my own question, but I want to be clear on the information you've provided and what I've read in the docs.  All that you've mentioned here is what can be done to the map after it already is on the screen, right?  Update based on regions changing, zoom in and out, etc.  It is NOT for sending continual updates when the map loads or after some time has passed, correct?  Can I assume that the map itself does not have events to handle the passage of time so that it can update itself when the user does not move?

Comment: That's correct, but pls don't use the comment section for questions. Other users with the same question won't find the answer this way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I guessed:

1. If the user drag the map, he wants to stay on that position.
2. If the user do nothing or reset to show current location, I need to follow the user.

I added a reset button to show the current user location like this:
[image]

On the reset button clicked, changed the `needToCenterMap` to `TRUE`

Added a drag gesture recognizer on map

```
// Map drag handler
    UIPanGestureRecognizer* panRec = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didDragMap:)];



- (void)didDragMap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        NSLog(@"Map drag ended");
        self.needToCenterMap = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Followed the user on map depending on `needToCenterMap` flag

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
if (self.needToCenterMap == TRUE) 
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Whats smAppDelegate I am getting Error :(

Comment: Answer updated. It should be `self.needToCenterMap`. Anyways the point was, I needed to set a flag and a reset button to decide whether I should follow user or not.

Comment: Doesn't zoom in user location :(

Answer (score 0):

This shell do the trick: `mkMapview.showsUserLocation = YES;`

Comment: How could this help with my Question:(